# Add offset to current page number in Winforms ReportViewer

Tags: winforms, reportviewer

I am working with the Winforms ReportViewer and I have the following problem: I would like to modify the start index for the page number.

For example, I have 3 reports, each one consists of 2 pages.
By using the expression: "Globals!PageNumber" I will get the current page number and "Globals!TotalPages" I will get the number of pages for each report. So the result will look like this:

Report 1: Page 1 of 2, Page 2 of 2

Report 2: Page 1 of 2, Page 2 of 2

Report 3: Page 1 of 2, Page 2 of 2

However, I would like to modify this into the following:

Report 1: Page 1 of 6, Page 2 of 6

Report 2: Page 3 of 6, Page 4 of 6

Report 3: Page 5 of 6, Page 6 of 6

The expression "Globals!TotalPages" can just be replaced by a constant (in this case number 6), that's not a problem.
However, regarding the current page number, I would have to add an offset to "Globals!PageNumber", for example for report 2: "Globals!PageNumber" + 2

Unfortunately, this does not work, because the expression "Globals!PageNumber" is only evaluated once the report has been created.
Is there a possibility to add an offset to the current page number?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a `TextBox` in footer/header to use an expression like this:

```
=Globals!PageNumber + 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! This solves the problem.